# There is no test with specified Id message while running Coded UI test in local machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to run coded UI test in my local machine but everytime I run the test case I get the below  message in my output window.
And it is not running any test case.

```
------ Run test started ------
UTA001: TestClass attribute defined on non-public class 
Raet.Testing.TestScripts.FlexBenefits.Initialization
There is no test with specified Id {ac3b157c-2594-5317-f826-52e0927cee39}.
```

Also there is no error message in error list window.

I am using visual studio professional 2015. 
I have also installed Visual studio professional 2017 in my machine.

In test assembly, I am using 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework version 14.0

OS - Windows 10. 
Test Solution was created using visual studio enterprise 2015
Let me know if any more details are required.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using visual studio professional 2015. And professional does not have support for coded UI.

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/

In order to run coded UI test we have to use visual studio enterprise version.
With enterprise version I am able to run Coded UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue because I added incorrect entry in app.Config and VS was not validating the same... After removing unwanted entry the error is not showing up